# How to write a Fortran program that supports both static and dynamic memory management?

Tags: memory-management, dynamic, static, fortran

I'm working on a public release if a model using Fortran 9x and I'd like to design the code to support both static or dynamic memory management.

I've only seen one example of a code that supports something like this. It is implemented using preprocessors that look something like this:

The code would include some memory management control file with the following:

```
#ifdef STATIC
  define NMEM_ N
  define PTR_      # blank
#else
  define NMEM_ :
  define PTR_ ,pointer
```

The user supplies the following file to configure static memory:

```
#define N 100      # Example array size
#define STATIC
```

In the core code, you declare your variable as such:

```
real PTR_, dimension(NMEM_) :: x
```

Set STATIC during compilation, and it becomes

```
real, dimension(100) :: x
```

Unset STATIC (implicitly setting it to dynamic) and it becomes

```
real, pointer, dimension(:) :: x
```

and some later code allocates the memory.

This works perfectly fine, but I like to avoid using preprocessors if I can, and it does feel like a kludge to me. Is there a more standard solution to this problem, or is this how it is normally handled? Is there even much difference between static and dynamic compilations these days (keeping in mind that I will probably want to use as much memory as I can)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having both static and dynamic memory modes seems to me an unnecessary complication, making your code harder to read and having two paths, both of which have to be tested.  It also creates more complicated instructions for the user, and a burden to follow when they "make" the program.   I recommend just using dynamic allocation if the maximum array size isn't known at compile time.  Furthermore, I recommend using allocatable arrays rather than pointers unless you need one of the few features that can only be achieved with pointers, such as arrays with non-unit strides.  Allocatables are safer, with memory leaks essentially impossible.  Fortran 95 compilers (dump any compiler than is only Fortran 90 at this point) have long supported dynamic memory allocation -- don't have any concerns about using it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Based on your suggestion, I probably won't implement the static memory allocation.

But I am concerned about performance: The model which used this method claimed about a 20% performance improvement in static-compiled code vs allocatable code. If that's the case, then I would imagine it's worth the hassle. Is this your own experience?

Comment: I haven't noticed any performance hit, but have rarely measured.  About the only case that I expect a performance penalty is if you made a call in which the actual and dummy arguments are incompatible, for example, the actual argument is a pointer with non-unit stride, and the dummy is a simple array -- in this case the compiler is likely to have to create a temporary array and use copy in/out.   In most cases the allocation will take a trivial time, then addresses will be passed.  Before doing anything complicated for speed -- measure!  Is code complication worth 20%?  Maybe x2...

Comment: A concern about execution speed is another reason to use allocatables rather than pointers unless you need a feature only possible with pointers.  In many cases with pointers the compiler must allow for the possibility of aliasing and the compiler may not be able to implement some optimizations.

Comment: Thanks again, I've always used allocatables myself, but I wasn't aware of the advantages/disadvantages vs. pointers. You've been very helpful, even if it wasn't the answer I was expecting. It's good to know that HPC F9x programmers prefer allocatable over static arrays. I hope to get further good advice in the future!